# Pandas: extractall - writing a capture group with or condition

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I need to extract a code from a dataframe column containing strings. These codes will have one of 2 2-char prefixes.

Ex.

```
PT00034
SA00043
SA44
PT554
```

When I test in a REGEX "Fiddle", this pattern will capture the first 2:

```
(PT|SA)[0-9]{5}
```

However, when I plug it into `extractall`, I get the following error:

```
df['Pat Capture'] = df['TextString'].str.extractall(r"((PT|SA)[0-9]{5})").groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ", ".join(x.unique()))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

I understand that extractall is seeing 2 groupings to extract but how do I rewrite the expression to both match one of several possibilities AND allow for zero padded numbers?

Comment: In short, use a non-capturing group, `r"((?:PT|SA)[0-9]{5})"`

Comment: Just tried it and I think it's working. So to clarify - it will include the prefix in the result but will signal that it is not a separate pattern to extract.